# NFC->SNEP-> GET request NOT_IMPLEMENTED?

Tags: android, request, nfc, nfc-p2p

i need my application to answer snep (simple ndef exchange protocol) GET requests. How can i do that ?

I can send PUT request succesfully; but my GET requests returns with "NOT_IMPLEMENTED" value. How can i write my application to answer that snep GET requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

On Android you can only use SNEP in combination with Android Beam. However, the SNEP server used by Android Beam implements the NFC Forum Default SNEP Server which is mandated by the NFC Forum's SNEP specification to always respond to Get requests with Not Implemented. From the SNEP specification:

> The default server SHALL NOT accept Get requests. The appropriate response for a Get request
>   message is Not Implemented.

Moreover, you can't easily implement your own SNEP server as Android does not have a LLCP API.